# Absolute position of container based on the Body container and not its Parent one

Tags: html, css, position

I need to set the position of a table container as absolute based on the `<body>` container rather than its nearest positioned parent container.

**Fixed position is NOT what I want** since it positions it based on the viewport and not the main body (this is the expected behaviour for fixed).

Here is a little more details and code showing what I want.

```
CSS:

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
I need the <table> content to have an absolute position based on the <body> container
and not the <div id="SearchForm"> container which is the nearest parent with its position set



HTML:
 <body>
        <div class="page"> <!--position: absolute;-->
            <div id="Header">  <!-- position: fixed;-->
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="header-secondary"> <!--position: absolute;-->
                        <div id="SearchForm"> <!--position: relative;-->
                            <form action="......">
                            ....<!--parent search bar form-->
                            </form>
                            <table> <!--quicksearch-->
                            ...content <!-- quicksearch results popup-->
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The reason behind this is that when the page is displayed in the mobile view for devices under 480px wide,

The `<header>` and `<div id=searchform>` stay fixed at the top of the screen/viewport regardless of scrolling down.

The `<table>` is the quickview search box that pops up during search showing nearest results.

The problem is, that this causes the quicksearch suggestion box to stay at the top as well. The rest of the page will scroll underneath it, but the suggestion box will stay "fixed" at the top of the screen.
This is somewhat fine if there were just a few results, but when there are more and it extends beyond the bottom of the screen/viewport, there is no way to scroll the suggestion box down to see the rest of them.

I could add a scroll bar for overflow but I want to be able to scroll beyond the quicksearch container and see the content of the main body if I keep scrolling down. As of now, the main content will scroll under the quicksearch results but always remain hidden under it.

if I use position:absolute; it will remain at the top of the screen and I won't be able to scroll down to the results that are offscreen.

If I use position:fixed; then the same thing will happen since it will be positioned based on its viewport and not based on the main body

My only current working option is to have the JS load outside DOM and thus have the ability place it anyway I want it.

This though creates other positioning issues when resizing the window beyond 480px for desktop view mode as it is harder to calculate the offset based on a child container that is deep in the body and keeps resizing dynamically when the window resizes.

Comment: `position: absolute` makes your element goes out of the flow of the html and you can position this element anywhere you want (with`top`, `right`, `left`, and `buttom` properties) in relation to ANY of the parent with NO `position: static` (propertie of all html by default).. with your current layout what you want to achieve it's impossible with css alone. Sorry about it

Comment: have you considered removing the position fixed on mobile with a media query. That would solve your issues I believe, and having halve your viewport covered on a small screen is just annoying anyway imo.

Comment: Well the part of the viewport that is covered is only 50px out of +600px average for most screens. I also need to keep it on top since the navigation menu is hidden in mobile view and its collapsable button needs to remain at the top of the screen at all times along with some other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the table to `position: absolute` relative to the body will be impossible as long as any of it's parents has `position: fixed`.

You will have to move the `<table>` outside of the fixed header one way or another.

I would use an extra wrapper to be able to switch which element has `position: fixed` at what viewport width:

```
<body>
    <div class="page"> <!--position: absolute;-->
        <div class="ExtraWrapper"> <!-- position: fixed; above 480px -->
            <div id="Header">  <!-- position: fixed; below 480px -->
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="header-secondary"> <!--position: absolute;-->
                        <div id="SearchForm"> <!--position: relative;-->
                            <form action="......">
                            ....<!--parent search bar form-->
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table> <!-- quicksearch. position: absolute; below 480px -->
            ...content <!-- quicksearch results popup-->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, this does work best so far (as i mentioned at the end of the question). the problem is that when in desktop mode, i need to keep it relative based on its parents position, so as that moves around, so will the quicksearch popup. i've made it follow it with offsets in the java code, but i don't really like the result. If i can't find a better answer though, i might have to go that route anyway

Comment: What is it with the javascript solution you don't like?

Comment: When using js to calculate the offset, it's based on the body container.  The problem is that the search bar is set to dynamically change size and position when resizing the window. The results box in this case is positioned slightly off to the left or right depending on the current screen size. My desired position and length is to be exactly the width and position as <SearchForm>

Comment: The only other solution i can think that would work exactly the way i want it is if i pull the searchbar container outside the header altogether, But that would just be bad coding and it wouldn't be true dynamic wrapping rather that clever media and positioning manipulation. I want my content to wrap because the container size changed and not because css told it to.

Comment: Have you tried using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to only move the table below 480px and leaving it unchanged above?

Comment: After reading a lot about it and getting my hopes up, matchmedia does all its media queries based on the viewport. There doesn't seem to be a way to query a nested element.